# On boot fsck ext2 issue

Tags: boot

[image]

What I should to so? Please help me thanks.

Comment: You will want to grab your Elementary installation USB (or DVD), use that to boot the system. Choose "Try Elementary" and load the UI. From there, run `fsck` on the internal drives.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll try that.